# Bootstrap: How i can create this layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How i can create this layout in Bootstrap 3 ?

[image]

Comment: Share the code what you have done so far.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/cwVEfWCL78

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Bootstrap **[push](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)** classes to achieve this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4"><div></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><div></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4"><div></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/Haq8HtocnV)**

Comment: You've saved my day !
Thanks ^_^